# REST API Salesforce Identity URL fails with 404 No_Access error (How to use admin user to read other user's information such as email_id?

Tags: rest-api, identity

I am using Salesforce REST API fetch the list of log files and getting events/records from each log file.
I have generated oauth2 token successfully.
Using token I can query list of log files and can see contents of each log file as well.

But when I use identity URL to get the non-admin user's Email Info it fails with 404 ERROR (No_ACCESS)
e.g.
https://login.salesforce.com/id/org_ID/user_id

How can I use the access token to see other user's email info ?
What settings I need to check for connected app ?
How can I allow admin user to read other user's info via REST API ?

Please guide.

I have used following steps to access the IDentity URL:
I have used following steps to get the access token.

curl --request POST 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token' 
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' 
--data-urlencode 'client_id=<consumer_key_connected_app>' 
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=<consumer_secret> 
--data-urlencode 'username=<system_admin_user>' 
--data-urlencode 'password=<password+security token>'

This gives me access token without any issues.

But the same access token when used with identity URL:

curl --request GET 'https://login.salesforce.com/id/ORG_ID/USER_ID' 
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>'

Returns 404 error saying No_access.

Tried with WORKBENCH and same Identity URL works fine.
So what's the difference between WORKBENCH and REST API access ?

I think I am still missing something. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The [access rules](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_using_openid.htm&type=0) are as follows:

> - The OAuth request for the access token includes the full or api scope.
> - The access token is for a user with the API Enabled permission.
> - The access token is for a user who has access to the other user according to the user sharing rules of the org.
> - The access token is for an internal user, meaning the user_type value in the response is STANDARD.

Assuming you meet these conditions, it should work. I just tested this in my org and got the expected response, so it certainly should be possible.

Alternatively, you can access similar data via `/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/User/:user_id`, but it'll have a different format.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the response.
How did you achieve those 4 conditions ?

I have 2 users. 1 is sys admin and other is non-admin.
Can you show me how did you achieve that ?
I can show you my setup for both users. My emailID is testmjvardhan@gmail.com
we can chat if you are ok.

Comment: @TestSalesforce (a) I used workbench (so, Full scope), (b) I used my admin account (so, Api Enabled, can see all users, and is internal user). I can set up a test org if you want a demo. I will be briefly unavailable this morning, but please feel free to message me on Hangouts, and I'll reply when I can. My user there is brianmfear.

Comment: I have used following steps to get the access token. Please let me know if it is missing anything.

--
curl --request POST 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=<consumer_key_connected_app>' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=<consumer_secret> \
--data-urlencode 'username=<system_admin_user>' \
--data-urlencode 'password=<password+security token>'

This gives me access token without any issues.

--

Comment: I pinged you on your hangout ID: Please let me know the suitable time to reach you.